# Has Putin's photo ops included wearing fluoro?

Tags: russian-federation

Apart from sport-related photo ops, one of the most frequent photo ops in Australia is the wearing of fluoro (Australian shortening of "fluorescent vest") by then PM Tony Abbott, preferably with a hard hat as well.

I'm under the impression that Russian leader Vladmir Putin does a lot of photo ops as well, with lots of shirtless Putin memes (maybe so Abbott can't shirtfront him). I've also heard that the TV news is often Vladmir this, Vladmir that, all the way through. So I tried googling for Putin fluoro, and couldn't find anything.

Has Putin's photo ops included wearing of fluoro?

Comment: What would be the relevance of that? What does "wearing fluoro" mean politically? V.g., a politician in campaign could wear work overalls to express his "working class" credentials, Putin posing as Lenin/Stalin/Peter the Great could have political significance, but what would express "wearing fluoro"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've certainly never seen Putin wearing a florescent vest. I suppose there is a reason for this: safety clothes are often associated with low-income and otherwise unattractive jobs. I have witnessed that attitude myself when I had to wear PPE (including a fluo jacket) while working on the railroad there - it's harder to get a taxi ride while wearing one. So I guess Putin doesn't want that kind of image.